# cuda and pytorch versions mismatch in conda

Tags: python, pytorch, conda

in my conda `test` env, when I trying install a third party lib by `python setup.py install`, I got the errors like:

```bash
File "/home/igs/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 387, in _check_cuda_version raise RuntimeError(CUDA_MISMATCH_MESSAGE.format(cuda_str_version, torch.version.cuda))
RuntimeError: 
The detected CUDA version (10.1) mismatches the version that was used to compile PyTorch (11.7). Please make sure to use the same CUDA versions.
```

I checked within the conda `test` env as below and got:

```bash
# check A
$ nvcc -V
...
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
```

```bash
# check B
$ nvidia-smi
...
CUDA Version: 12.1
```

```bash
# check C
$ python3 -c "import torch; print(torch.__version__)"
2.0.1+cu117
```

```bash
# check D
$ conda list | sed -n "3p" && conda list | grep -i -E "cuda|torch"
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
cudatoolkit               10.2.89              hfd86e86_1    defaults
ffmpeg                    4.3                  hf484d3e_0    pytorch
pytorch                   1.9.1           py3.8_cuda10.2_cudnn7.6.5_0    pytorch
torchaudio                0.9.1                      py38    pytorch
torchvision               0.10.1               py38_cu102    pytorch
```

as my understanding, `check B` is ok, `check A` and `check D` matches, but `check C` is mismatch and looks like it used another version `torch/pytorch`. Why this happends and how to overcome it? Thanks for any advice.

p.s. in this conda `test` env, I installed `pytorch` according to [offcial](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/#linux-and-windows-16)

`conda install pytorch==1.9.1 torchvision==0.10.1 torchaudio==0.9.1 cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch`

#### update 1

```bash
#check E
$ pip list | grep -i -E "cuda|torch"
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu11               11.7.101
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11               11.7.99
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11             11.7.99
torch                                2.0.1
torchvision                          0.15.2
```

Answer (score -1):

after `export PYTHONNOUSERSITE=True` within conda `test` env, looks like the problem overcomes.

ref:
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7707

Comment: You can see that torch is not picked up from within your env, but from `/home/igs/.local`. You might want to consider deleting the version there